# WPF: Как растянуть отдельные контролы в WrapPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl Name="Items"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type grace:Present}">
            <local:PresentView Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Items}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type grace:RelayCfg}">
            <local:RelayCfgView Margin="0 2 2 0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Мне необходимо растягивать все `PresentView` на все доступное пространство по горизонтали, а остальные контролы в зависимости от того сколько их помещается, но например, если в строку не влазит 3 контрола, то предыдущие два должны ее заполнить.

Вот разметка `PresentView`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MainBrush60}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MainName"
           TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BaseBrush}"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Border>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0"
                Background="{StaticResource MainBrush60}">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MainName}"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </Border>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"
                      Margin="5"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type grace:ByteProperty}">
                    <local:BytePropertyView/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: Ваш `PresentView` должен просить себе всё доступное пространство у панели

Comment: @АндрейNOP выставить HorizontalAligment?

Comment: Не, это не поможет. Сейчас попробую поэкспериментировать. `PresentView` - это у вас User Control или что?

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, добавил его разметку в вопрос.

Comment: *если в строку не влазит 3 контрола, то предыдущие два должны ее заполнить.* - заполнить как? оставшееся пространство поровну между собой разделить? Или всё пространство на 2 равные части? А если влазит 3 (или больше), то заполнять не надо — пусть остается пустое пространство? Или тоже надо? А по высоте контролы разные могут быть? Или все одинаковые?

Comment: @АндрейNOP у контролов второго типа одинаковая высота, у них есть минимальная ширина, если удается всунуть три, то вставляем три, если не удается, то растягиваем два на поровну. И так далее, если удается всунуть, например, 5, то вставляем их, если нет, то растягиваем 4 и растягиваем их.

Comment: Добавил код панели.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во время компоновки каждый контрол опрашивает вложенные элементы и узнает сколько они хотят себе места, передавая при этом в метод количество имеющегося места.

Нам же нужно чтобы контрол просил себе всю доступную ширину. Это просто — перегрузим метод `MeasureOverride` вашего `PresentView`:

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
{
    // Берем корневой элемент (в данном случае это Border)
    var child = (FrameworkElement)Content;
    // Командуем ему рассчитать необходимое место
    child.Measure(constraint);
    // Говорим опрашивающему нас контролу что нам нужна вся
    //  доступная ширина и высота, которую "заказал" дочерний контрол
    return new Size(constraint.Width, child.DesiredSize.Height);
}
```

---

По поводу второй части вопроса всё немного сложнее — придется писать свою панель.

Так как вы не предоставили хорошего минимального самодостаточного примера, я использую следующее. В главной VM коллекция, которая может содержать элементы разных типов:

```
public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<object>
{
    "string 1",
    "string 2",
    3,
    444444444,
    "string 5",
    5555,
    6666666,
    7,
    888888888,
    999999999
};
```

Пара представлений, для строк (с красной рамкой):

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

в этот контрол я добавил метод, приведенный в первой части ответа, т.е. элементы со строками будут растягиваться на всю ширину панели.

И для чисел (с зеленой рамкой):

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Теперь, разметка окна:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <c:FillingPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:String}">
            <c:StringView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:Int32}">
            <c:Int32View/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Она похожа на вашу, но здесь используется самописная панель, код которой мы сейчас напишем. Этот код минимальный рабочий, панель умеет располагать элементы только сверху вниз. При желании вы можете доработать самостоятельно, например, добавить возможность горизонтального размещения элементов, добавить AP для обозначения принудительного "конца строки" и т.д.

Код панели с комментариями:

```
public class FillingPanel : Panel
{
    // Этап подсчета занимаемого места
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        double width = 0, maxWidth = 0, y = 0, nextY = 0;
        foreach (FrameworkElement child in Children)
        {
            // Запрашиваем измерение желаемого размера
            child.Measure(availableSize);
            // Если элемент помещается в текущую строку
            if (width + child.DesiredSize.Width <= availableSize.Width)
                // увеличиваем ширину текущей строки
                width += child.DesiredSize.Width;
            // иначе
            else
            {
                // предполагаем размещение элемента в следующей строке
                width = child.DesiredSize.Width;
                y = nextY;
            }
            // Запоминаем максимальную потребную ширину
            if (width > maxWidth)
                maxWidth = width;
            // и высоту панели
            if (y + child.DesiredSize.Height > nextY)
                nextY = y + child.DesiredSize.Height;
        }
        return new Size(maxWidth, nextY);
    }

    // Этап размещения элементов
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        double y = 0, nextY = 0, width = 0;
        // Коллекция, содержащая элементы текущей строки
        var line = new List<FrameworkElement>();
        foreach (FrameworkElement child in Children)
        {
            // Если элемент уместится в текущей строке
            if (width + child.DesiredSize.Width <= finalSize.Width)
            {
                // Помещаем его в список элементов
                line.Add(child);
                // Подсчитываем потребную ширину строки
                width += child.DesiredSize.Width;
                // Подсчитываем смещение по вертикали следущей строки
                if (y + child.DesiredSize.Height > nextY)
                    nextY = y + child.DesiredSize.Height;
            }
            // иначе
            else
            {
                // Размещаем строку
                ArrangeLine(line, finalSize.Width, y, nextY - y);
                // Элементы следующей строки
                line = new List<FrameworkElement> { child };
                width = child.DesiredSize.Width;
                y = nextY;
                nextY = y + child.DesiredSize.Height;
            }
        }
        // Последняя строка
        ArrangeLine(line, finalSize.Width, y, nextY - y);
        return finalSize;
    }

    private void ArrangeLine(List<FrameworkElement> line, double lineWidth, double y, double lineHeight)
    {
        // Потребная ширина строки
        double width = line.Sum(fe => fe.DesiredSize.Width);
        // Делим оставшуюся часть длины строки на все элементы
        double delta = (lineWidth - width) / line.Count;
        // Смещение элемента внутри строки
        double x = 0;
        foreach (var fe in line)
        {
            // Вычисляем ширину текущего элемента
            double curWidth = fe.DesiredSize.Width + delta;
            // Размещаем элемент
            fe.Arrange(new Rect(x, y, curWidth, lineHeight));
            // Вычисляем смещение следующего
            x += curWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

Пример работы панели:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Теперь пропал `ItemsControl` , который лежит внутри `PresentView`

Comment: Когда закоменчиваю метод MeasureOverride, все появляется обратно.

Comment: Хм, не должен. Вроде нормальный код. `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Items}"` удалили из разметки?

Comment: При этом, когда я изменяю настройки BytePropertyView, который лежит внутри ItemsControla в PresentView размер меняется, но содержимое не отображается

Comment: Да, сразу же это сделал

Comment: Поковыряйтесь с помощью окна Live Visual Tree в дереве.

Comment: Все решилось добавление праметра Height="auto" для воторой строки Grid внутри PresentView. Хотя я так и не понял, как это повлияло.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!
Я так понимаю, что для реализации второй части вопроса мне нужен этот же метод, только с более сложной логикой проверки макс и мин значений?

Comment: Пустое пространство выделялось? Странно.

Comment: На сколько я понял - да, проверил изменением фона всего ItemsControl и цвет менялся, похоже на него задавалась высота какая-то

Comment: Со второй частью непросто, как бы не пришлось писать свою панель. Лучше эту часть вопроса вынести отдельно. И постарайтесь приводить такие примеры в вопросах, чтобы его можно было малой кровью запустить

Comment: Фишка в том, что править UserContol без толку, сама панель должна этим заниматься, возможно малой кровью удастся наследоваться от `WrapPanel` и реализовать свои `MeasureOverride` и `ArrangeOverride`. Почитайте Адама Натана, там последняя, вроде, глава как раз про эти нюансы и написано как писать такие панели (там и читать не много)

Comment: А какую книгу конкретно? Я знаю, что у него их несколько...

Comment: У меня только эта есть: "WPF4. Подробное руководство (2011) - Адам Натан"

Comment: А что вы еще можете посоветовать почитать? И какие книги должны быть всегда под рукой для wpf разработчика?

Comment: Я читал только Адама Натана. Иногда в него заглядываю + гугл-фу + реже всего исходники WPF. Есть еще у меня "Windows Presentation Foundation в .NET 4.0 с примерами на C# 2010 для профессионалов (2011) - Мэтью Мак-Дональд", не читал, но на первый взгляд там примерно всё тоже самое, что и у Натана. К тому же на professorweb копипаста из Мак-Дональда.

Comment: Спасибо! Уже читаю книгу, которую вы посоветовали!
Как доделаю текущие таски вернусь к доработке панели!