# Задать ItemTemplate для ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Хочу сделать следующее:

1. Привязать список моделей к `ItemsControl` как `ItemsSource`
2. Для каждого элемента создавалась бы `ViewModel`, с конвертером из `ViewModel`'и во `View`

Тестовые списки моделей и конвертер есть, но не могу понять как это реализовать.

То что я пробовал, не дало вообще никакого эффекта.

Но есть один вариант в правильности которого не уверен, т.к. там пришлось вместо списка моделей, отдавать список вью моделей.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Serials.Serials}">
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Converter={catel:ViewModelToViewConverter}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Как реализовать задуманное если оно будет тратить меньше ресурсов на обработку списка, чем приведенный выше вариант?

Comment: Ваша установка `ItemsControl.Template` выглядит подозрительно. Для смены панели используйте свойство `ItemsPanel`, сейчас вы полностью весь шаблон контрола меняете, в итоге он состоит из одной лишь Wrap-панели

Comment: @АндрейNOP: за подсказку спасибо, но мне всеравно придется использовать `Template`, т.к. нужен скроллбар =)

Comment: Поместите весь `ItemsControl` в `ScrollView`. Хотя, нет, правильное решение здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/790467/218063 Да, там переопределяется `Template`, но важно в нем не потерять `ItemsPresenter`! А панель если будете менять, все равно нужно помещать ее в свойство `ItemsPanel`

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Да, не плохо, но эффект один и тот же =) Узнать бы еще как расположить элементы так что бы они были на равном расстоянии друг от друга в зависимости от ширины контролла в котором лежат, а не кучковались по левому краю.

Comment: Написать панель свою, потому что штатных таких панелей нет. Че-то я потерял нить, в чем вообще суть этого топика?

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Вообще речь шла о том как привязать список моделей к `ItemsControl`, но так, что бы на каждый из заданных элементов, `View` сам бы инициализировал другую `View`. Вот.

Comment: Ну это делается с помощью `DataTemplate`

Comment: А вот здесь можете взять `FillingPanel`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/856685/218063

Comment: Вот, кстати, изучите тот ответ тщательнее, там и про DataTemplate написано