# Распределить ряд кнопок. Т.е. задать всем кнопкам такой Padding, чтобы они были разной ширины и полностью заполняли окно по ширине

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

Имеется набор кнопок с контентом разной ширины типа горизонтального меню. Надо каким-то образом задать всем кнопкам одинаковый Padding, чтобы они (кнопки) были разной ширины и полностью заполняли окно по ширине (ни больше, ни меньше). Желательно средствами XAML.

Comment: Список кнопок динамический? Покажите разметку того, что у вас есть сейчас

Comment: Как вариант, написать свою панель для этого, кажется это несложно должно быть

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/856685/218063 здесь есть панель почти такая как вам нужна